# Acumatica Customization (Framework vs ERP) not consistent with TXX guides

Tags: acumatica

I was asked to create a new maint page where data could be added. Just like in the T100 series part1:Maintenance pages. Immediately a few issues arise, why in the Acumatica ERP project I am unable to complete the steps done in the Framework application? I tried to add a new item -> PXgraph option(as described in the instructions) was not available, I couldn’t even add my own c# class from scratch the option was not listed. Instead it just listed page options(will add screenshots below). I attempted to create a new .cs file outside the scope of the project and import it into the file and it wouldn’t recognize it as an available file to import. In the end I attempted to manually drag and drop the file into the Objects folder I wanted the file to be a part of.

[image: Framework file options]

**VERSUS ERP Add new item**

[image]
Secondly, I created a new ListView in the page. I was not able to choose my Typename:SO.SOusrPhoneExtMaint.cs file from the list of options. I have rebuilt the project numerous times to see if that was the issue. I manually added the TypeName by going into the source of the aspx and typing it my graph. When I tested the graph I got the following errors that “Invalid type PX.Objects.SO.SOUsrPhoneExtMaint specified for datasource.” My question is why is there a discrepancy between the framework and the erp application for customization and how do I customize the graphs and pages if they don’t take the same approach as the TXX development guides. If I am doing something fundamentally wrong I'd like to know what is the right approach.
[image: Error in visual studio]

Comment: Just realized. Are all customization ONLY available for completion through the project customizer via the web application GUI for the ERP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use the Customization Project Editor for any customization of Acumatica ERP.
To add a custom form, perform the following actions:

1. Navigate to the **Customization Projects** form (SM204505; System > Customization > Manage)
2. Select an existing customization project or create a new project by clicking "+" on the form toolbar
3. Click the project name to open the project in the Customization Project Editor
4. On the navigation pane of the editor, select **SCREENS** to open the Customized Screens page
5. On the page, click **ADD SCREEN > CREATE NEW SCREEN** to open the Create New Screen dialog box
6. Fill all the required fields and click OK to obtain workable template of your custom form

The New Screen wizard creates the form template and includes it as the following items in the customization project:

- two *File* items - .aspx page code for the new form
- a *Code* item - code template for business logic controller
- a *Page* item - the link to the new page content, which you can further develop by using the Layout Editor
- a *SiteMapNode* item - the site map object of the new form

(For an example see **Lesson 11: Creating a Custom Form** of the **T300 Acumatica Customization Platform** Training Guide)

Further you can develop the items by using the tools you prefer.
The custom form will be added to Acumatica ERP after the project is published.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed guide on creating the screen via the customization gui. I appreciate it.

Comment: Edit: Found that i can ONLY edit aspx via the customize project screens. Constant errors appear when trying to change the Masterview name.

Comment: To change the Masterview name, perform the following actions:
1. Change the name in the data view declaration of the graph
2. Specify the same name in the ASPX code:
 a) in the PrimaryView property of the PXDataSource control
 b) in the DataMember property of the container controls (PXGrid, PXFormView...)
3. If you make changes on the file system, update the files in the project (using the Detect Modified Files dialog box)